# How to select properties from an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following object say,

```
{"id":"kl45wkfj1k4j34", "firstname":"Arun", "lastname":"K"}
```

and I have the key to be filtered, *'firstname, lastname'* assigned in a string using comma separator.

How do I filter that object to get the output as follows:

```
{"firstname":"Arun", "lastname":"K"}
```

Comment: That object has an invalid key and value.

Comment: corrected the key value pair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underscore's [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) method is what you're looking for.

```
var obj = { "id": 'kl45wkfj1k4j34', "firstname": "Arun", "lastname": "K" };
var filter = 'firstname, lastname',
var result = _.pick(obj, filter.split(', '));
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) comes in handy ba using an array of key/value pairs.

To prepare this, you copuld split the string and map the pairs first.

```js
const
    object = { id: 'kl45wkfj1k4j34', firstname: "Arun", lastname: "K" },
    filter = 'firstname, lastname',
    keys = filter.split(', ');
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, object[k]]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ramanareddy438, or take the edited above with your array, like `result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));`

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways one could go about this. The answers so far assume you want to modify the existing objects but the question doesn't specify; the word "filter" suggests maybe not. So if you want to create a new filtered object, rather than mutate the existing one(s), you might employ a reduce function. You said your key list is a string, but for the sake of keeping the examples clean, let's assume you just do `str.split(',')` or similar so it's already an array before passing it to these functions.

## ES5

```
function createObjectFilter(keys) {
  return function(obj) {
    return keys.reduce(function(acc, key) {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
}

var myFilter = createObjectFilter([ 'a', 'b' ]);

var filteredObject = myFilter(object);
```

## ES6

```
const createObjectFilter = keys => obj => keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = obj[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

const myFilter = createObjectFilter([ 'a', 'b' ]);

const filteredObject = myFilter(object);
```

Now, the createObjectFilter function returns the actual filter function based on a given list of keys. You could make it "all in one", instead, but the advantage of this approach is that it becomes possible to reuse your filters in more situations. For example:

```
const filteredObjects = unfilteredObjects.map(myFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var toBeFilteredObject = {...}; // {"id":"kl45wkfj1k4j34", "firstname":"Arun", "lastname":"K"}
var filteredObject = {};
'comma, seperated, string'.split(',').forEach(function(key) {
  key = key.trim();
  filteredObject[key] = toBeFilteredObject[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this object:

```
 var obj = {"id":"kl45wkfj1k4j34", "firstname":"Arun", "lastname":"K"};
```

Then you can do this:

```
delete obj.id;
console.log(obj);
```

Now as per comment:

```
var newlist = listarray.map(function (obj){
      delete obj.id;
       return obj;
});
```

This will create a new list array with no  `id`.

---

Or with specific keys:

```
var newlist = listarray.map(function (obj){
       var o = {};
        o.firstname = obj.firstname;
        o.lastname = obj.lastname;
       return o;
});
```

Comment: I get this, but the thing is like I have list of keys to be filtered as a string seperated by comma.  Any generic solution suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Using `_.reduce`

```
var data = {"id":"kl45wkfj1k4j34", "firstname":"Arun", "lastname":"K"}
var filters = 'firstname, lastname'.split(', ');
_.reduce(data,function(result,value,key){
 if(filters.indexOf(key)!=-1){
   result[key] =value
 }
 return result;
},{})
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic solution if you have the array

```
var obj = [{ "id": 'kl45wkfj1k4j34', "firstname": "Arun", "lastname": "K" }, { "id": '34234', "firstname": "kajshd", "lastname": "ajsdh" }, { "id": '263742', "firstname": "asdjasd", "lastname": "asdjahs" }],
    filter = 'firstname, lastname'.split(', '),
    result = {}; 
var output = [];
obj.forEach(function(i, j) {
  filter.forEach(function (k) {
    // console.log(obj[j]);
    result[k] = obj[j][k];
  }); 
  output.push(result); 
  result = {};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the solution from @Nina to **TypeScript**, adding an improvement to it.

```
/**
 * Constructs a new object by picking certain properties of the given object.
 * Example: `const publicUser = pick(user, ['id', 'name'])`.
 * Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667463/4034572.
 */
export function pick<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T,
  keys: K[]
): Pick<T, K> {
  const entries = keys.filter((k) => k in object).map((k) => [k, object[k]])
  return Object.fromEntries(entries)
}
```

Usage example:

```
type User = {
  readonly id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

type PublicUser = Pick<User, 'id' | 'name'>

const user: User = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Albert',
  email: 'a@a.co',
  password: 'pwd',
}

const publicUser: PublicUser = pick(user, ['id', 'name'])
// publicUser is { id: 2, name: 'Albert' }
```

The nice thing is that TypeScript will not allow you to use an invalid key. For example, doing `pick(user, ['xyz'])` raises the error *TS2322: Type '"xyz"' is not assignable to type 'keyof User'*.

And you'll get autocomplete too :)

**Improvement**

I've added `filter((k) => k in object)` because without it doing `pick(user, ['xyz'])` would give `{ xyz: undefined }`, adding a property that doesn't exist on type `User`.

However, with the `filter` it correctly gives `{}`, which is what makes sense since the property `xyz` does not exist on `User`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const form = { some: "one", prop: "two", value: "three", foo: "f", bar: "b"},
hasFilled = Object.values(
    Object.fromEntries(
      "some, prop, value".split(", ").map((k) => [k, form[k]]),
    ),
  ).every((i) => i !== "");
```

with checking if has value on filtered property

Answer (score -1):

If you are having array of objects then use this

```js
 data = [{
   "id": "kl45wkfj1k4j34",
   "firstname": "Arun1",
   "lastname": "K1"
 }, {
   "id": "kl45wkfj1k4j14",
   "firstname": "Arun2",
   "lastname": "K2"
 }, {
   "id": "2",
   "firstname": "Arun3",
   "lastname": "K3"
 }];

 data = data.map(function(o) {
   delete o.id;
   return o
 })

 document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```